# Sub types with swagger API

Tags: rest, swagger

I have an API that exposes a resource such as `/stores`. The problem is that stores have different types which require different JSON schemas (there are only 4 types though).

My question is how can I use swagger to validate the incoming data based on the type of store. Is it possible to have conditional checks based out of type with swagger or should I look into creating sub-types such as

`/stores/it`

`/stores/cars`

...

Comment: different resources for one path? I don't think that's poosible...

Comment: Do the store types have any common properties?

Comment: the stores have most of the attributes common, different are just a few but are essential. in ooo paradigm they subclass the same base and override only a few properties

Comment: Inheritance/polymorphism can be implemented using `discriminator` - check  out [Swagger Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27862407/113116) and [“discriminator” in polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39683846/113116).

Comment: Hi Helen, i did ... but is no clear way on how to handle it into the parameters section, even though I use parameters : [ {"name": "stores",  "in": "body", "schema": { "$ref": "#/definitions/BaseStore" } } ] and I send data such as {"kind": "carStore", "name": "newCarStore"} ... I get 400 bad request.

Comment: Hi Helen, I found out where the error was - the definitions of the models was missing type: object into each store type, there was not error when parsing but was not processing ok - if you want to convert you comment to answer I would gladly accept it - thanks!